# Is it possible to list games owned by the user using Epic Games' API?

Tags: api

I know that Steam does offer such information on their API using [GetOwnedGames](https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/webapi/IPlayerService) but does the Epic Games API have that too?

I did check their API and found that they do have an OAuth API, but can't find info about owned games.